# C# Out of Memory error after recall the function

Tags: c#

I am attempting to uncompress a large amount of data and I use the following code.    The first iteration finishes just fine and then on the next iteration I get  an error :
"An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code"

```
private static void UnCompressP(byte[] buffToUnCompress, int index, AutoResetEvent eventToTrigger, ref MemoryStream[] memStream)
{
    eventToTrigger.Set();
    MemoryStream cmpStream = new MemoryStream(buffToUnCompress);

    GZipStream unCompZip = new GZipStream(cmpStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);

    byte[] unCompressedBuffer = new byte[buffToUnCompress.Length];

    MemoryStream msToAssign = new MemoryStream();
    int read = 0;
    while (0 != (read = unCompZip.Read(unCompressedBuffer, 0, buffToUnCompress.Length)))
    {
        msToAssign.Write(unCompressedBuffer, 0, read);
        msToAssign.Flush();
    }
    memStream[index] = msToAssign;

    unCompZip.Close();
    cmpStream.Close();

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have too much data to store it all in memory at once.  You may need to avoid doing that, and instead only ever act on streams that allow you to keep only a small portion in memory at any given point in time.

Comment: Additionally you can switch your solution to target x64 instead of x86. That will lift the memory restriction of ~2GB for .NET processes to a usable value.

Comment: I have dll files that are not compatible with x64.Is there another option.

Comment: Can you please show the code that is calling the method?

Comment: The code is part of class 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49264/Parallel-fast-compression-unleashing-the-power-of

Comment: [for(int j =0;j< Convert.ToInt16(NO_S.Text); j++)
                                {
 FastCompress.CompressFast(fileshare + name.ToString() + Convert.ToString(copy.Extension),fileshare +"s"+ name.ToString() + Convert.ToString(copy.Extension),true);]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not disposing anything. Every stream needs to be disposed by calling its `Dispose()` method or preferably by enclosing it with `using { }`

That should be enough, but if you are really critical on memory you might not be able to wait garbage collector to reclaim memory back so you might also need to call the garbage collector at the end of the method:

```
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;   
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: I agree that the OP isn't disposing - and that may help in this case - but I don't think it's ever a very good solution to call `GC.Collect()`. The only time I find that useful is in timing code execution.

Comment: @Enigmativity as I have said he should try first without that. GC.Collect() is there exactly because it is useful sometimes and yes it is even a good practice to call it if unusually huge part of memory becomes free. I had to write the app that works with 20 MB that creates objects of several megabytes and you can't even think of doing that without calling GC. I mean the only other option is to crash and it is much worse than calling GC.